# Libgdx for Windows Phone 8

Tags: game-engine, libgdx, windows-phone-8

I want port my libGDX game to Windows Phone.

Can I compile my libGDX game for Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not directly.  Currently, libGDX "only" works for Mac, Windows, Android, HTML5 (via Google Web Toolkit), and (beta) iOS.

You may be able to make the HTML5 output run on a Windows Phone (depends on how spiffy the JavaScript engine in the browser is).  Then you'd need some way to package this for Windows Phone (on Android or iOS you could use PhoneGap, there may be some equivalent for WP8).

The iOS support for libGDX is actually done [via a C# cross-compiler](http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=2450) (!!?), so you may be able to use that step to build something that might run on the WP CLR.  However, it looks like [that won't be easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8786823/can-a-java-library-compiled-to-a-dll-be-used-in-developing-a-wp7-application).  It should be possible to use (and probably improve) other tools to translate/convert a libGDX application to WP, but doing so would probably be a lot of work.

Comment: May be its more easy for WP8, then WP7?

Comment: In fact, the HTML5 Part is done using WebGL- Microsoft may never support this technology at all... Same problem persists using C# or Native code as the Drawing is done using OpenGL wich neither Windows RT nor Windows Phone (7 or 8) support. So you would be off writing your own wrapper.

Comment: libgdx doesn't use C# anymore for running on iOS. instead it uses [RoboVM](http://www.robovm.org/) now.